# How can I find out what are my EntityValidationErrors when I am using Entity Framework 5 and dbContext?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server. I am doing an insert of data but getting the following:

```
public partial class TestContext : DbContext

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.ApplyRules(); 
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }


Validation failed for one or more entities. 
See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Can someone tell me how I can find out more information on what are the Validation errors?

I looked at the exception details but it does not give any details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I use:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ApplyRules(); 
    try
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        Exception raise = dbEx;
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(), validationError.ErrorMessage);
                //raise a new exception inserting the current one as the InnerException
                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message , raise);
            }
        }
        throw raise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. I will look into using this. I also wonder about the code I use to call this. I will open a new question asking about that in a few minutes. Thanks again !